# Populate unbound text filed in MS ACCESS report via tempvars populated from a dlookup function

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'll try my very best to explain what I'm trying to bo. I'm still kinda novice in MS ACCESS and still trying to learn stuff. So what I'm trying to do is to populate the control source of an unbound textbox in Report. If for example I use this code `="<p>my name is <b>" & [fullname] & "</b>.</p>"`, it will work. The `[fullname]` field will be populated by the value assigned to it. But if I put that same code in a table then use the dlookup function to store the code in tempvars then use the tempvars to populate the unbound textbox, it will not work.

The unbound textbox is set to rich text so it recognizes the `<b></b>` and makes it bold but the value for the `[fullname]` field is not populated. It will just be returned as: my name is **" & [fullname] & "**.

Is there a way to do it so ms access will still populate the `[fullname]` value and not translate it literally?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this question. It's just easy as targeting the ControlSource. So instead of targeting directly the unbound textbox by `Me.Content = ([TempVars]![FirstResponse])`. I targeted the ControlSource `Me.Content.ControlSource = ([TempVars]![FirstResponse])`. This did the work. It acknowledged both the HTML tags and returned the value of the field ex `[fullname]`.

I still thank you ShieldOfSalvation for making me think that there is a way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Eval function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Eval-Function-8c4a1b10-85ba-40db-b0c8-5290da4d4166), e.g.,

```
="<p>my name is <b>" & Eval([fullname]) & "</b>.</p>"
```

Actually, in your case maybe this might be better:

```
=Eval("<p>my name is <b>" & [fullname] & "</b>.</p>")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it but it didn't work. What I did was I put the whole code `=Eval("<p>my name is <b>" & [fullname] & "</b>.</p>")` in the table's column being pulled by the dlookup and set it as a value of a tempvar. :( It was translated as a literal string with `" & [fullname] & "` rendered bold.

Comment: What is the data type or object type of [fullname]? Is it a bound field on your form? Or is it a column in the data source for the form?

Comment: It is a value in a table. Data Type: Long Text. Text Format: Plain Text. But the unbound textbox in the report where this value is being fed is in Rich Text Format.

Comment: Oh sorry. The `[fullname]` is one of the columns of the record source for a report.

Comment: Instead of setting the data source for the unbound textbox, try setting the value of it with your code.

Comment: That works. If I put it directly as the value of the unbound box. But it will not work if I will use a dlookup to set the value of the unbound box. I'm trying to make the Report as dynamic as possible making the content of the unbound text box dynamic depending on what button the user clicked. But I guess it is just not possible. I'll just make multiple copies of the report with different values in the unbound box and just trigger the specific Report depending on what button the user clicks.

Comment: If you want to make the content of the unbound text box dynamic depending on what button the user clicked, at which point you use a DLOOKUP to set the value of the unbound box...then I presume there is some VBA code behind the Click event of the button, and in it you've coded the DLOOKUP. Show me what those lines of code look like, the lines where you perform the DLOOKUP and then set the value of the textbox. What you are trying to do is not impossible. We just need to see what you are working with!

Comment: Here's a sample VBA in a button:
`TempVars("FirstResponse") = DLookup("ValueName", "Info", "FieldName = 'FirstResponse'")`

Here is the value in the table Info being called by the DLookUp:
`="<p>This is to <b>CERTIFY</b> that <b>" & [fullname] & "</b> is a bonafide resident of this community who is living in <b>" & [fullAddress] & "</b>.</p>"`

Here's the VBA in On Load Event of the Report connected to the unbound text box named Content:
`Me.Content = ([TempVars]![FirstResponse])`

Comment: Do you have a field on your report that is called [fullname], and is bound to that table column by the same name?  If not, create it. You can simply hide it out of view (set Visible = False) so it won't clutter your actual presentation. Try your report with that. While you're at it, create the same for [fullname] if you don't already have it.

Comment: I don't have the field in the report. I just dropped it now as you instructed but the unbound textbox is still showing the literal string.

Comment: Since you just dropped the [fullname] field into the report, do you see it beaing loaded with the correct information from data row to data row (as you cycle from record to record using the next/previous record buttons)? I just want to determine that it is properly bound. Questions: (1) the button that you are clicking, what is its button title text and primary function? (2) What is the actual name of the unbound textbox, for future reference in our discussion? Let's assume it's "X".

Comment: (3) You said you're trying to make the "unbound text box [we called it 'X'] dynamic depending on what button the user clicked". Are these buttons merely forward/backward buttons to advance to the next/previous record? Because if so, then perhaps you just want to set the unbound textbox's value during the AfterUpdate event. In that event you could set the unbound textbox's value like this: X.Text =Eval(TempVars("FirstResponse")).

Comment: The button is just a simple button with title naming the different kinds of certificates/clearances. So the Report is like a standard letter template with all the regular contents on it. The user will click the button bearing the name of the kind of certificate they wish to print. Those buttons trigger the DLookUp function in it and pulls the appropriate content for the unbound textbox X in the Report "Standard Letter Template" from the table "Info". So these buttons are not use to navigate but to trigger the whatever DLookUp function coded to it.

Comment: Got ya. Then on the Click event, set TempVars("FirstResponse") = DLookup("ValueName", "Info", "FieldName = 'FirstResponse'") and the next line is X.Text =Eval(TempVars("FirstResponse")). You need not set X's data source nor value field. Just do everything programmatically from the Click event.